# How to change table html with inputs using JQuery

Tags: jquery, input, replace, classname

I have a table with a list of countries as radio inputs. When the user clicks on a country, a second table appears which gives them 2 options. Currently, the 2nd table inputs are:

```
<td><input class="rr ref1" id="ref1" name="reference" type="radio" /> Who xx references</td>

<td><input class="rr ref2" id="ref2" name="reference" type="radio" /> Who reference xx</td>
```

**I want to replace the 'xx' with the specific country selected.**

I've used `$("td:contains('xx')").replaceWith("COUNTRY")` but this replaces the html with just plain text.

When I try to replace the entire td code the JQuery script doesnt run

$("td:contains('xx')").replaceWith("`<td><input class="rr ref1" id="ref1" name="reference" type="radio" /> COUNTRY</td>`")

I want to replace the text with the class name of the country selected but I cant get that to work either
`$("td:contains('xx')").replaceWith($(this).className.text())`.

Any help or guidance as to where to look would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use JS replace()? Smth. like this:

```
$.each($("td:contains('xx')"), function(k, v) { 
    var str = $(v).html();
    $(v).html(str.replace("xx", "COUNTRY"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, that works. I cant seem to replace the text with the class name though. I tried using
$(this).attr("class")
but that comes up as undefined. However when I check the class with an alert box, it gives me the class fine

alert($(this).attr("class"));

Comment: Get the class name before $.each() loop, assign it to a variable and use that variable inside the loop. Inside the loop "this" is the entire element.